# Is DbSet.Add (and other non-DB operations) thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I get it that all the operations involving the DB access should not be called in parallel. Creating DbContext is cheap, use the new one, all that.

But what about the local operations, like `DbSet.Add(...)`, or `DbSet.Local.<...>`? They happen almost instantly, so the chances of race conditions are extremely low, but still. What are the underlying containers in DbSet? Do they support thread-safe operations?

Answer (score 1):

Based on a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/5962) and [this answer](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/5962#issuecomment-230535384), DbSet is not considered thread-safe. The responses from the GitHub issue indicate that anything in EFCore that is not a singleton should be considered non-thread-safe.